# Garbage values --> ��� are coming in the description of swagger-ui (io.swagger) in spring-mvc , How to remove this?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, garbage

> I have confiured io.swagger for my spring-mvc application. The problem is that the garbage values --> ��� are in the description part of the defined parameter as shown in screen shot below.
>
> I have defined this parameter using @ApiImplicitParam
>
> Below is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Api(value = "TestApi", description = "Descriotion")
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/apiTest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiOperation(notes = "The Test API", value = "Response")
@ApiImplicitParams(value = {
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "employee", value = "Test description for question purposes", dataType = "string", paramType = "query")
            }
public String getTestData(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "test";
}

}
```

> The string the "value" of @ApiImplicitParam is giving ���, Below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have some weird characters in your source code? `value = "Test desc`, try to use some text editor to see if you have any such chars in that exact spot.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling utf-8 encoding be adding below lines in header HTML file.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3525

Comment: i am using io.swagger in this applicaton and hence have no control over ui-files of swagger. Is there any other way to do this

Answer (score 1):

```
  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "employee", value = "Test description for question purposes", dataType = "string", paramType = "query")
            }
```

You're getting a garbage value error because,
In above code you've done a mistake of dataType = "string" Instead it will be like dataType = "**String**".
The compiler doesn't understand the dataType as you've defined in your code that's why it's printing garbage values instead of an actual values.